# How do I deploy a ktor project to a hostgator site?

Tags: kotlin, deployment, ktor

I'm starting to learn server side development that doesn't involve my old acquaintance PHP. I have kotlin experience from Android development and am looking to leverage that using ktor for my app's server side. I can find all sorts of tutorials in getting a ktor project set up and tested locally. What I can't find are any steps in how one would get it uploaded onto my web host (hostgator).

I'll take any route needed, from building a war to dancing around a fire and chanting. ;)

Comment: You can find the documentation about various ways of deploying Ktor server applications here https://ktor.io/docs/deploy.html so you need to figure out what way your web hosting supports.

Comment: I ended up deciding to go with Nodejs.